# How to pack referenced libraries into a new libarary

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

When creating a new library `MyAPI.dll`, I am referencing many other (non-standard) libraries such as `RestSharp.dll`, `Newtonsoft.dll`,`MyUtilities.dll`, etc. My library works fine in my development environment because I've downloaded all of those other libraries and they're sitting in my project's bin folder, but as soon as I try to publish that library and use it in a new location, it fails because the referenced libraries cannot be found.

How to I set up my `MyAPI.csproj` project so that these dlls/libraries get packaged into my published `.dll` file, and future users of `MyAPI.dll` don't have to worry about downloading and referencing those dependencies?

Thought this would be simple, but my google-fu is weak today. Setting those external references to `CopyLocal = False` removes them from the `/bin/` directory, giving the illusion that they are getting packaged into MyAPU.dll, but really Visual Studio is just adding them to my Global Assembly Cache (GAC), which doesn't help future users of the API.

Comment: I don't know if there's potential copyright infringement, but you could just distribute those libraries with your DLL.

Comment: Well let's say I just wanted to package my own libraries. For the sake of modularity, I have many different csproj's with various utilities that I recycle in my own applications. It there no way to link them all together as a resource to some production library short of duplicating all their source code files into a common project?

Comment: If that were the case and ALL the code is mine, I'd probably have one project that LINKs all the files into it. That can still feel like a chore though and I hope there's a simpler answer.

Comment: It just so happens that my particular library (which I wanted to release in conjunction with an ExcelDNA XLL Add-in) could be merged into the XLL using the bundled ExcelDnaPack utility. That being said, I didn't have to resort to any of the solutions below, so I will accept the highest rated solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options (as far as i know):

1. [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx)
2. Embeded Resource and Assembly.Resolve (see [Jeffrey Richter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx))

First you can use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx), which is comamndline program that can merge multiple .NET assemblies together, creating one output file. It cant merge WPF projects. Can be added to postbuild events to make the merge automatic.

Second is adding library as embeded resource to your project, and then registering to [Assembly.Resolve event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) and loading assembly when its needed from resources. Article from Jeffrey Richter about this method: [Jeffrey Richter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx).

The second method has major drawback, it doesnt work with merging multiple libraries into one (it can only be used for adding libraries to executable), at least in c# without another tool. To add library to library you have to use another tool, which is mentioned in Jeffrey's article comments at second page: ([Module initializer injection](http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/)).The problem with embeding library into other library is that you cant (at least in c#) register to Assembly.Resolve event before the embeded library is needed, so you need to inject the registering to module initializer using the [Module initializer injection](http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/). It can also be set as build event, which is written on the apge with the tool. It may sounds complicated, but once you set it up its easy.

Comment: I thought this was a common thing to do. Had no idea I'd have to resort to third party tools or strange techniques. Thanks for this though.

Comment: As answer for your comment in your question (i dont have rights to comment on your answer), i believe you cant, you have to use ILMerge or Assembly.Resolve. Or you could just distribute then with your app/library, but then you would need to distribute multiple files.

Comment: Odd how everybody's memory of setup.exe is fading fast.

Answer (score 3):

There is a free nuget package "Costura.Fody" it packs dependency assemblies as resources into your assembly. The solution works with WPF and other managed assemblies.

If the dependency assemblies are not in the executing folder, the packed assemblies are taken automaitcally. It also configures your msbuild targets automatically for packing the dependencies during build. You do not have to add code in your assemblies.
It also lets you configure, which assemblies to pack or not in a xml file.

It uses a combination of two methos:

- Jeffrey Richter's suggestion of using embedded resources as a method of merging assemblies.
- Einar Egilsson's suggestion using cecil to create module initializers.

You can find documentation here: https://github.com/Fody/Costura/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

It's not free (well there's a trial) but a friend of mine told me about a program called [.NET Reactor](http://www.eziriz.com/dotnet_reactor.htm), which has the ability to package an exe with dependent DLL's into a single executable, well worth a look.

I would say the next most straight-forward alternative would be ClickOnce, [a good tutorial is here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/37db1d/deploying-wpf-application-with-clickonce-deployment-techniques/).

Comment: Not building an executable or WPF application, so these don't apply.

Comment: Surely .net reactor still applies?

Comment: Well this doc file (http://www.eziriz.com/help/merge.html) seems to have a lot of the keywords I'm looking for, but it all seems to require building into an executable. Furthermore, the main purpose of the program (obfuscation) goes against my purpose which is to create a public API .dll that anyone can use. The obfuscation process would turn it from a .NET assembly into something native, limiting it's usability.

Comment: No problem, well it looks like @Krtek was able to point you in the right direction :)